# accessing data using ajax page methods directly

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

I want to access data and show in label ajax page methods but data is not displaying.

```
PageMethods.GetDataFromDB(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
         //}
        function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
            var jsonData = eval(result.d);
            $get('Label1').innerHTML = jsonData.FirstName;
        }    
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetDataFromDB()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryGetPerson = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("server=xe; uid=system; pwd=;"))
        {
            string Command = "Select * from tblSavePerson";                //selecting Top 1 Row in Oracle
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Command, con);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DictionaryGetPerson.Add("FirstName",dr["FirstName"].ToString());

            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       return js.Serialize(DictionaryGetPerson).ToString();
```

}

table has only one row.

Comment: showing actual data what i want.

Comment: which version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: @naveen: I'm using asp.net 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have given the tags as jQuery and jQuery Ajax I am deviating a little from the solution.

Do these things

1.Wrap your `WebMethod` in a try-catch block. try-catch are there for a reason.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDataFromDB()
{
    try
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryGetPerson = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("server=xe; uid=system; pwd=;"))
        {
            string Command = "Select * from tblSavePerson";                //selecting Top 1 Row in Oracle
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Command, con);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DictionaryGetPerson.Add("FirstName", dr["FirstName"].ToString());

            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(DictionaryGetPerson).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        throw new Exception(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Please note that this Dictionary will fail with Duplicate Key error if you have more than one row. If there are no errors lets move to step 2.

2.Do not use <strike>`PageMethods.GetDataFromDB`</strike>. It very *ancient*. [Using jQuery  one can consume ASP.NET Ajax Page Methods directly](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). Call Page method like this.

```
function LoadNames() {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: "{}",
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Test1.aspx/GetDataFromDB',
        success: function (msg) {
            OnSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //alert("error");
            //OnFailed(a, b, c);
        }
    });
}

function OnSucceeded(dict) {
    var jsonData = dict.hasOwnProperty("d") ? dict.d : dict;
    var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
    alert(json.FirstName);

}
```

Also, don't <strike>`eval(result.d)`</strike> when we have `$.parseJSON` in jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but i wanted to to this using page Pagemethods class. I am sure it will be done using above method.

Comment: function OnSucceeded(dict) { var jsonData = dict.hasOwnProperty("d") ? dict.d : dict; var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData); alert(json.FirstName); } This function not working...Do i need add a reference of json library.

Comment: Yeah...I have found wat the actual problem was.